RMarkdown issue: {r child = here::here("scripts","rmd","analysis-part000.Rmd")}
I'm trying to clean up a long RMarkdown document based on this article that uses here::here() to dynamically build the folder structure from the base folder of the project.
My code successfully accesses the child file, but it is not processing the R code.  I've tried bringing the Child file as .Rmd and .R.  I've removed all the other options called in the Code Chunk {r}.  But nothing brings in the contents of the file and then runs the code.  Feel like I'm missing something simple.
Here's the contents of the Main (Parent) .Rmd document:
Preface
An analysis of data published by the Bureau of Transportation Statistics on the number, type, and location of border crossings into the USA.  Data is reported monthly since 1997.  Here are supporting [details] and [data dictionary] for the dataset.
This is an explanatory style analysis done in R. A complementary exploratory dashboard built with Tableau is available.
This section gives a high-level overview of the US-Canada and US-Mexico borders, the Ports of Entry spread across those borders, and where the volume of border crossings happen.
{r child = here::here("scripts","rmd","analysis-part000.Rmd")} 
Here's the top section of content from the child (analysis-part000.Rmd) file.
##########################################################################################################################################
# Analysis Part 000 
##########################################################################################################################################

##########################################################################################################################################
# Main Data Wrangling
##########################################################################################################################################
  
# Loading the data from CSV file, 
data_00_base <- data.frame(reader(here::here("Documents","Projects","usa-inbound_border_crossing","data/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data.csv"))
# data_00_base <- data.frame(data_00_base)
# cleanse commas (e.g. 12,000) from the field that holds the measures numeric values
data_00_base$Value <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", data_00_base$Value))

# Add some features to the BASE data frame.  This is the BASE that all sub-queries (data frames) will pull from.
data_00_base_mod <- data_00_base %>%
  mutate(Border_Code = ifelse(grepl("Canada", Border, fixed = TRUE), "CAN", "MEX")) %>%
  separate(Date, c("Month", "Year"), remove = FALSE)  %>%
  # mutate(Measure = factor(Measure, order = TRUE, levels = c("Bus Passengers","Buses","Pedestrians","Personal Vehicle Passengers","Personal Vehicles","Rail Containers Empty","Rail Containers Loaded","Train Passengers","Trains","Truck Containers Empty","Truck Containers Loaded","Trucks"))) 
  # mutate(Measure = factor(Measure, order = TRUE, levels = c("Personal Vehicles","Personal Vehicle Passengers","Pedestrians","Trucks","Truck Containers Loaded","Truck Containers Empty","Buses","Bus Passengers","Trains","Train Passengers","Rail Containers Loaded","Rail Containers Empty"))) 
  mutate(measure_summary = factor(Measure, order = TRUE, levels = c("Personal Vehicles","Personal Vehicle Passengers","Pedestrians","Trucks","Truck Containers Loaded","Truck Containers Empty","Buses","Bus Passengers","Trains","Train Passengers","Rail Containers Loaded","Rail Containers Empty"))) %>%
  mutate(Measure = factor(Measure, order = TRUE, levels = c("Trains","Train Passengers","Rail Containers Loaded","Rail Containers Empty","Buses","Bus Passengers","Trucks","Truck Containers Loaded","Truck Containers Empty","Pedestrians","Personal Vehicles","Personal Vehicle Passengers"))) %>%
  # mutate(Year_num) = as.integer(Year)
  mutate(state_delete_me = State) %>%
  mutate(crossing_date = as.Date(paste(Month," 1, ",Year), format = "%b %d, %Y"))

Here's what's rendering in the knitr call to build the RMarkdown document.  It's printing the R code instead of processing it and doing the data wrangling.

What am I doing wrong here?

From the snippet of your Rmd file it looks like it is simply an R script. Hence, the code is rendered as text. Try with putting your code in a code chunk.

@stefan - I had already tried that option, but not successfully.  I went back through and cleaned up the approach to have clean code chunks in my child documents. After some tinkering I got things to work and I'm off and running!  Thank you for the  feedback.
